# Using a temporary table in dynamic sql in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I am writing a Store Procedure in SQL Server 2012.
I have a temporary table defined like so:

```
  DECLARE @CURRENT_RET_WEEK_PTIMEIDS TABLE ( PTIMEID INT )
```

I am also using `EXECUTE` to write a dynamic SQL query. Is there any way I can join this table onto the above temporary table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use local temp-table -

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp (ID INT)
INSERT INTO #temp (ID)
VALUES (1),(2)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM #temp'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```